# R MuMIn model.avg() - relative importance not working with pasted formulae

Tags: r, mumin

I am trying to use MuMIn's model.avg function with model formulae that are pasted and use an index rather than directly input, for example:

```
m1<-gls(as.formula(paste(response,"~",paste(combns[,j], collapse="+"))), data=dat)
```

'combns' is a 2D array created by combn() containing combinations of predictor variables. This is producing model-averaged coefficients and AICc values identical to those produced if the gls functions contain the formulae directly, e.g.:

```
m1<-gls(median_Ta ~ day_of_season + hour_of_day + pct_grey_cover + 
    foliage_height_diversity + tree_shannon_diversity + median_patch_size, data=dat)
```

However, the relative variable importance is not computing, and I believe this to do with the use of a for loop or with using a variable to access the index of the list in which the models are stored somehow causing the component model terms not to be 'read' properly (see the term codes for the models):

```
Component models: 
         df  logLik   AICc delta weight
1234567b  7 -233.08 481.43  0.00   0.59
1234567f  3 -237.97 482.21  0.78   0.40
1234567e  4 -241.32 491.08  9.65   0.00
1234567a  9 -241.15 502.39 20.96   0.00
1234567c  6 -248.37 509.68 28.25   0.00
1234567d  5 -250.22 511.11 29.68   0.00

Term codes: 
           day_of_season foliage_height_diversity              hour_of_day 
                       1                        2                        3 
       median_patch_size           pct_grey_cover   tree_shannon_diversity 
                       4                        5                        6 
 urban_boundary_distance 
                       7
```

This results in the relative variable importance being given as:

```
Relative variable importance: 
                     day_of_season foliage_height_diversity hour_of_day
Importance:          1             1                        1          
N containing models: 6             6                        6          
                     median_patch_size pct_grey_cover     tree_shannon_diversity
Importance:          1                 1              1                     
N containing models: 6                 6              6                     
                     urban_boundary_distance
Importance:          1                      
N containing models: 6
```

Whereas if I use model.avg over the same models with the formulae typed individually, I get the following, correct output:

```
Component models: 
        df  logLik   AICc delta weight
23456    7 -233.08 481.43  0.00   0.59
1        3 -237.97 482.21  0.78   0.40
57       4 -241.32 491.08  9.65   0.00
1234567  9 -241.15 502.39 20.96   0.00
1467     6 -248.37 509.68 28.25   0.00
147      5 -250.22 511.11 29.68   0.00

Relative variable importance: 
                     pct_grey_cover median_patch_size tree_shannon_diversity
Importance:            0.6           0.59              0.59                 
N containing models:     3              4                 3                 
                      foliage_height_diversity hour_of_day day_of_season
Importance:           0.59                     0.59         0.4        
N containing models:     2                        2           4        
                     urban_boundary_distance
Importance:          <0.01                  
N containing models:     4
```

How can I make model.avg read the predictor variables in the formulae properly? I've only included six models as an example here but I want to compare the full set of 128 models (and I have other response variables with larger numbers of predictor variables), so typing them out individually isn't feasible.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: reproducible example**

It took me a while to narrow down the problem. The first example, m.ave, shows the problem in action with a for loop. The second example, m.ave2 shows it working with the indices typed rather than using a variable. Obviously this is just a small subset of the predictor variables.

```
require(nlme)
require(MuMIn)

dat<-data.frame(median_Ta=rnorm(100), day_of_season=runif(100), hour_of_day=runif(100), pct_grey_cover=rnorm(100),
        foliage_height_diversity=rnorm(100), urban_boundary_distance=runif(100), tree_shannon_diversity=rnorm(100), 
        median_patch_size=rnorm(100))

f1<-"median_Ta ~ day_of_season + hour_of_day + pct_grey_cover + foliage_height_diversity + 
        urban_boundary_distance + tree_shannon_diversity + median_patch_size"

f1<-gsub("\\s", "", f1) # remove whitespace
f1split <- strsplit(f1, split="~") # split predictors and response
response <- f1split[[1]][1]
predictors <- strsplit(f1split[[1]][2], split="+", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]

modelslist<-list()

combns <- combn(predictors, 6)
for (j in 1:7) {
    modelslist[[j]]<-gls(as.formula(paste(response,"~",paste(combns[,j], collapse="+"))), data=dat)
}

m.ave<-model.avg(modelslist[[2]], modelslist[[3]], modelslist[[4]],
        modelslist[[5]], modelslist[[6]], modelslist[[7]], modelslist[[8]])

summary(m.ave)

#compare....

modelslist2<-list()
modelslist2[[1]]<-gls(as.formula(paste(response,"~",paste(combns[,1], collapse="+"))), data=dat)
modelslist2[[2]]<-gls(as.formula(paste(response,"~",paste(combns[,2], collapse="+"))), data=dat)
modelslist2[[3]]<-gls(as.formula(paste(response,"~",paste(combns[,3], collapse="+"))), data=dat)
modelslist2[[4]]<-gls(as.formula(paste(response,"~",paste(combns[,4], collapse="+"))), data=dat)
modelslist2[[5]]<-gls(as.formula(paste(response,"~",paste(combns[,5], collapse="+"))), data=dat)
modelslist2[[6]]<-gls(as.formula(paste(response,"~",paste(combns[,6], collapse="+"))), data=dat)
modelslist2[[7]]<-gls(as.formula(paste(response,"~",paste(combns[,7], collapse="+"))), data=dat)

m.ave2<-model.avg(modelslist2[[1]], modelslist2[[2]], modelslist2[[3]], modelslist2[[4]],
        modelslist2[[5]], modelslist2[[6]], modelslist2[[7]])

summary(m.ave2)
```

Comment: can we have a reproducible example ... ??

Comment: @BenBolker - sorry, took me a while to get one as the problem wasn't quite where I thought it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the `formula` method for `gls` (in package `nlme`). Since the actual formula is not stored anywhere in the object, it evaluates `"model"` argument in the function call. In case of elements of `modellist` they are all the same, for example:

```
modelslist[[1]]$call$model
modelslist[[7]]$call$model
```

both return

```
> formula(paste(response, "~", paste(combns[, j], collapse = "+")))
```

which, when `eval`uated use the current (last) value of `j`, so that all `formula(modellist[[N]])` returns the last model formula.

```
 all.equal(formula(modelslist[[1]]), formula(modelslist[[7]]))
```

returns

```
> TRUE
```

Needles to say, all this confuses `model.avg` which uses the formulas to build the model selection table (this is a fallback because `gls` lacks `terms` as well).

**Edit: possible workarounds**

Much easier way to get what you want:

```
model.avg(dredge(..., m.lim = c(6,6)))
```

or, if you want to make predictions:

```
modellist <- lapply(dredge(..., m.lim = c(6,6), evaluate = FALSE), eval)
```

But, if you want to use an arbitrary set of models, replace the `$call$model` element in each `gls` model object with a proper formula, e.g.

```
combns <- combn(1:7, 6)
modellist <- vector("list", 7)
for (j in 1:7) {
    f <- reformulate(predictors[combns[, j]], response = response)
    fm <- gls(f, data = dat)
    fm$call$model <- f # assign the actual formula
    modellist[[j]] <- fm
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am having the same issue with gls and nlme. @Kamil Barton, I tried your workaround: `model.avg(dredge(..., m.lim=c(6,6))) but get the following error: Error in lme.formula(fixed = response ~ a + c + c + a:b +  : 
  unused argument (m.lim = c(6, 6))`    Where was the `m.lim` argument created? Also, what if you want to include the `weights` argument in gls? That is not include in the "predictors" variable?

Comment: @LiveLongandProsper Regarding the error, check your code for typos. As for the questions, please be more specific.

Comment: `model1<-gls(Response~ a*b*c,weights=varIdent(form=~1|a), method="REML",data=dat)`

`Dredge_model1<-dredge(model1, rank="AICc", trace=TRUE)`

`model1_gen_workaround <- model.avg(get.models(dredge(model1, 
                                                                  rank = "AICc"), subset = delta <= 141), m.lim=c(3,3))` 

`importance(model1_gen_workaround)`   Even with the workaround, the results for relative importance of each predictor are still all "1" (as in the given problem example above). Are there other steps besides adding `m.lim`?

Comment: "This is a bug in the formula method for gls (in package nlme). " Do you know if a bug report has been submitted? If so, maybe this has been fixed by package creators?

Comment: @LiveLongandProsper: `m.lim` is an argument of `dredge` not `model.avg`.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it! Correct input: `model.avg(get.models(dredge(model1, rank = "AICc",m.lim=c(3,3)), subset = delta <= 141))`

Comment: Hello again @KamilBarton. Do you know if this bug also exists for glmer using binary distributions? model.avg(get.models(dredge(Survival_glmm_binary1, 
                                                            rank = "AICc",m.lim=c(0,7)), subset=TRUE)) . For all combinations of m.lim, I always get "1" for the importance of every factor. I don't know if this is an "error" or if the factors are all equally weighted.

Comment: @LiveLongandProsper: It may be so. According to `lme4:::formula.merMod` code, formula can be taken from the model call. Check your component models and `dredge` output.